# Why did public transport in London and Northern Ireland avoid privatisation?

Tags: united-kingdom, transportation

In the 1980s Margret Thatcher embarked upon the [privatisation of British industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thatcherism).  Part of this was the sale of previously state owned public transport across the country.  However, this did not occur in London or Northern Ireland.  Buses and trains in both places operate under large public corporations: [Transport for London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_for_London) and [Translink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translink_(Northern_Ireland)) respectively.  Why?

Comment: Strictly speaking Transport for London doesn't operate any services directly. It runs the underground train system via London Underground Limited and it franchises the overground train and bus services to commercial operators (who own their respective fleets).

Comment: For London at least, it's perhaps worth looking at the history of [London Regional Transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Regional_Transport#History) and the Wikipedia article on the [Privatisation of London bus services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatisation_of_London_bus_services).